# Run Jenkins Job Based on Another Job's Status

Tags: maven, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I have a number of different projects, with Jenkins CI jobs configured for each of them to run tests. When I create a new release, I have a second job that coordinates between a number of different jobs that go over each of the modules in the projects and updates the versions and the dependencies in the pom.xml's. I would like to make the "update" job conditional on the status of all the CI jobs - meaning that if one of the CI jobs is not green, then the update job will not run at all.

I had a look at the [Run Condition Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Run+Condition+Plugin) as well as the [Conditional BuildStep Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Conditional+BuildStep+Plugin), however it does not seem possible do configure them to be dependent on the status of another Jenkins job.

Answer (score 0):

you could hit the other jobs via the API at `[JOB_URL]/lastCompletedBuild/api/json` and verify the `result` for each.

to mess around with this:

```
curl `[JOB_URL]/lastCompletedBuild/api/json` | jq '.result'
```

you probably want `result` to say `SUCCESS`.

this is not fancy, but you don't want fancy in CI; you want something that is not likely to break when you upgrade jenkins. :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a [https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin] ["Multijob Plugin"] ,

In your case, you can add a job in first step and configure in that step, at which result condition of first step, you want to run second step. 
Again, in second step, you can configure one/many jobs and can also configure if you want to run them  in parallel.